# How can I send an email using a template?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a email template in ExactTarget API and I want to use it executing XML from SoapUI.

Is there any tutorial or examples of how can this be done?

I'm new at this and I'm not sure how ExactTarget really works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method in the API that you will want to use will depend on the type of email that is being sent.  If you are looking to send a marketing email to a list of subscribers then you could use the EmailSendDefinition object or the Send object.

Send Object - It is a simple way to perform a send to a list:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_send_object/

EmailSendDefinition - Can be used for more advanced scenarios such as sending to data extensions:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_performing_and_deleting_email_send_definitions/

Alternatively, if you are looking to send transactional ad-hoc type emails (For example a confirmation email after a purchase), then a TriggeredSend would want to be used:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_triggered_email_campaign_workflow/

In order to send with a template in ExactTarget - you would need to follow the [documentation here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_an_email_via_the_web_service_api/). At the bottom there is a section on "Creating an Email Message Using a Template".

In that section, notice that the SOAP packet sets the template up.  In order to get that template, you will first need to retrieve the [template object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/template/)

When sending email strictly through the API, using templates is not really required, and slightly cumbersome.  Using templates to create templates for future usage in the UI is ideal, but when performing sends through the API only, sending your HTML through directly is the best approach.

Comment: The section "Creating an Email Message Using a Template" is gone. Is there an update to the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I built a Nuget package to create emails from Templates. You can view source code here of how I build up the XML and do something similar.

https://github.com/alwynlombaard/exacttarget-email-from-template-creator/blob/master/ExactTarget.EmailFromTemplateCreator/EmailCreator.cs#L151

Project site here:
https://github.com/alwynlombaard/exacttarget-email-from-template-creator

Hope this helps